# Vim: Changing Buffer Numbers

Tags: vim, buffer

I usually like to use buffer numbers to go to buffers quickly. Unfortunately, after many searches, opening some files, etc., the buffer numbers get crazy:

1. Is there anyway to assign buffer numbers manually?
2. Is there anyway to restart buffer numbering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to assign buffer numbers manually, or reassign them for that matter. The only way to restart buffer numbering is to restart vim. You might be interested in the [SelectBuf script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=107).

Comment: No offense intended… Once you know about https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411885/117471 the SelectBuf script seems less like a solution to the problem "I need a convenient way to change buffers" and more of a solution to "I like GUIs".

Answer (score 18):

*"the buffer numbers get crazy"* Tell me about it! By the end of the day I'm easy over 100 buffers. But luckily, as you can see in this animation, you have <kbd>tab</kbd> completion for buffer names.

[image: Hit :b se<Tab>]

So, even though you can't renumber the buffers, you can still jump around easily.

It's also worth noting that it is doing `*str*` matching so I didn't have to search on "se" to go straight to that file. Typing `:b up`<kbd>tab</kbd> would have also taken me straight there. If there are more than one match, subsequent <kbd>tab</kbd>s will cycle over the matches (circularly). So, in this session I could cycle over my "test" files or my "py" files if I wished. **This is BETTER than renumbering once you learn it!**

Comment: A very useful part of this answer was seeing that you can enter the buffer command without closing the list created by :ls.

Comment: @Gregory, yes in fact, one of my favorite mappings is `nnoremap <Leader>b :ls<CR>:b<Space>` which allows me to type `\b` to get the initial view (minus the "se" on the end). I use it all the time. And when I'm on a system without it I can still do it manually. I think you should try to have memorized anything that you map. Otherwise you are gimped when on a new server.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out a way to do this. Use `mksession: {session_filename}`, close out your session, open ***{session_filename}***, Look for the lines with `badd {filename}`, add/edit/delete/arrange these lines, then open it again with `vim -S {session_filename}`. The buffers will be in the new order. Be careful with deleting if it was a current or active file. I will be referenced in other places.

Answer (score 2):

Try [bufferexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42) plugin for vim. It's also usefull to map some keys to Fx keys,here's an example:

```
"Bufexplorer mapings
nmap <F5> <Esc>:BufExplorer<cr>
vmap <F5> <esc>:BufExplorer<cr>
imap <F5> <esc>:BufExplorer<cr>

" F6 - previous buffer
nmap <F6> :bp<cr>
vmap <F6> <esc>:bp<cr>i
imap <F6> <esc>:bp<cr>i

" F7 - next buffer
nmap <F7> :bn<cr>
vmap <F7> <esc>:bn<cr>i
imap <F7> <esc>:bn<cr>i
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this [buffer-enancment](https://github.com/gelus/vim-buffer-enhancement) plugin.

It is a small layer over native buffer switching that lets you assign buffers numbers and recall them by that number like such:

assign current buffer to the number 1

```
1<leader><C-6>
```

when you want to load that buffer switch to it like you would normally switch to buffer 1

```
1<C-6>
```

It works by saving a dictionary of the buffers you assign loading them instead of the regular buffer if one is present. If the key is not present it will simply try to load the buffer with that number.